# How to redirect to another controller action in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two controllers `search` and `tweet`:

I am in search and I want to go to tweets controller index action to list all tweet in DB. I tried many things with `redirect_to` but it did not work. I usually get this error `NoMethodError in Home#search`.

search.html.erb:

```
<%=client.search("#{params[:search]}", result_type: "recent").take(5).collect do |tweet| %>
    <% @tweeter = Tweeter.new(image: tweet.user.profile_image_url ,sender: tweet.user.name ,tweet: tweet.full_text ,date: tweet.created_at)%>
    <% @tweeter.save %>
    <%= redirect_to  tweeters_path %>       
<%end %>
```

tweet controller:

```
def index
    @tweeters = Tweeter.all
end
```

and I get this message:

[image]

NOTE : when I search any thing in twitter the result will be saved in DB and when I type URL https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.c9users.io/tweeters  all data in DB will be listed. But I want after search to go directly to https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.c9users.io/tweeters

Comment: Please put your  source code and log.

Comment: you can write a new controller action in search controller which will give you list of all the tweets from the DB. Have you tried this ?

Comment: it saved in DB and I can listed. However, I want to listed them directly. Now I have to edit URL manually to show all Listed in DB

Comment: You should use `link_to` in views not `redirect_to`.

Comment: link_to will show me the link. What I want is Type any thing to search in twitter the save result in DB and then show the result from DB.So, I have to write any word and click search only

Comment: As you said I cannot use redirect to in view so, I search for another way and I fount this   window.location.href="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.c9users.io/tweeters"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redirect_to is a method of ActionController::Base Class so you can not use it in ActionView.

Instead you can try like this:

```
<% if @tweeter.save  %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href="/your_path"
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing stuff in your view what should be done in a controller. You should probably read up on MVC (see here for example [MVC on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

To your problem: You could render a partial there. 
replace your redirect... with

```
render(:partial => 'name_of_partial')
```